# solve sympy assuming parameters aren't the same

Tags: python, sympy

the list of equations i want to solve is:

```
equations = [Eq(λ0, α00), Eq(3*λ0, α01), Eq(2*λ0, α10), Eq(4*λ0, α11)]
```

and it gives me [], also Linsolve() is giving me EmptySet
but shouldn't it return λ0 = α00 = α01/3 = α10/2 = α11/4?
i tried to run it on the idle and on the terminal, my code is pretty long but if u need more details just ask
α00, α01, α10, α11 are parameters and i solve it like

```
lambdas = [λ0]
solve(equations, lambdas)
```

i retrive the values like this :

```
def MatriciGeneratrici (entries,lambdas, label5) :
    for h in range(0,len(entries[0])) :
        for o in range(0, len(entries[0][h])):
            expr = 0
            for j in range(0, len(entries)-1) :
                expr += lambdas[j] * (sympify(entries[j][h][o].get()))
                print(expr)
            print(entries[-1][h][o])
            equations.append(Eq(expr, sympify(alfas[h][o])))
```

where alfas contains the alfas symbols

Answer (score 2):

You only list `λ0` as an unknown so the other symbols are all considered to be symbolic parameters. In the case of symbolically parametrised equations sympy's `solve` function will return solutions that are valid for *generic* values of the parameters. For generic values of `α00, α01, α10, α11` your equations have no solution which is why an empty list is returned. If you want these symbols to be considered as *unknowns* rather than *parameters* then you should include them in the list of unknowns:

```
In [10]: print(solve(equations, [λ0, α00, α01, α10, α11]))
{α00: α11/4, α01: 3*α11/4, α10: α11/2, λ0: α11/4}
```

You have here 4 equations but 5 symbols and the system of equations is underdetermined meaning that solve will arbitrarily choose one of the 5 symbols to act as a free parameter in the solutions for the other 4. It is also possible to choose any 4 of the symbols as unknowns in order to express each of those in terms of the 5th symbol. The gives 5 different forms for the solution:

```
In [12]: print(solve(equations, [α00, α01, α10, α11]))
{α00: λ0, α01: 3*λ0, α10: 2*λ0, α11: 4*λ0}

In [13]: print(solve(equations, [λ0, α01, α10, α11]))
{α01: 3*α00, α10: 2*α00, α11: 4*α00, λ0: α00}

In [14]: print(solve(equations, [λ0, α00, α10, α11]))
{α00: α01/3, α10: 2*α01/3, α11: 4*α01/3, λ0: α01/3}

In [15]: print(solve(equations, [λ0, α00, α01, α11]))
{α00: α10/2, α01: 3*α10/2, α11: 2*α10, λ0: α10/2}

In [16]: print(solve(equations, [λ0, α00, α01, α10]))
{α00: α11/4, α01: 3*α11/4, α10: α11/2, λ0: α11/4}
```

If you allow fewer than 4 symbols to be unknowns then the system is underdetermined and (generically) has no solutions.

Confusion around symbolic parameters and the genericity of solutions comes up a lot so I will explain here clearly what is meant by that. First consider equations with no symbolic parameters:

```
In [21]: from sympy import *

In [22]: x = symbols('x')

In [23]: solve([Eq(2*x + 3, 1)], [x])
Out[23]: {x: -1}

In [24]: solve([Eq(2*x + 3, 2)], [x])
Out[24]: {x: -1/2}

In [25]: solve([Eq(2*x + 3, 3)], [x])
Out[25]: {x: 0}
```

Here the rhs is always a concrete number and we tried three different values for that number. We might be interested in obtaining the solution for an arbitrary rhs which we could indicate by making the rhs a symbol `t`:

```py
In [26]: t = symbols('t')

In [28]: print(solve([Eq(2*x + 3, t)], [x]))
{x: t/2 - 3/2}
```

This shows that if the rhs of the equation is `t` then `x = t/2 - 3/2` and that will be a correct solution for `x` for *any* possible value of the rhs `t`. This is useful because we can solve for `x` first and then substitute a value for `t` later and the solution will be correct whatever value of `t` we might choose afterwards.

Note that although there are two symbols in the equation `solve` has solved for `x` only and that is because `solve` was instructed by the second argument `[x]` to treat only `x` as an unknown. The equation is an equation for the unknown `x` that is parametrised by the symbolic parameter `t`. The solution returned by `solve` is a parametric solution given in terms of that same symbolic parameter and is valid for all possible values of the parameter.

When we have more than one equation it becomes frequently possible that there will be no solutions to the system of equations for example:

```
In [29]: solve([Eq(x, 1), Eq(x, 2)], [x])
Out[29]: []

In [30]: solve([Eq(x, 1), Eq(x, 3)], [x])
Out[30]: []

In [31]: solve([Eq(x, 1), Eq(x, 4)], [x])
Out[31]: []
```

Here the two equations contradict each other in each case and so there are no values of `x` that can simultaneously satisfy both. In each case we get an empty list. Now let's make the rhs a symbolic parameter `t`:

```
In [32]: solve([Eq(x, 1), Eq(x, t)], [x])
Out[32]: []
```

Here we get an empty list as well and this generalises the three cases before in which we did not get a solution for `t=2`, `t=3` or `t=4`. However this result does not hold for *every* possible value of `t`: if `t=1` then the equations do have a solution for `x`:

```
In [33]: solve([Eq(x, 1), Eq(x, 1)], [x])
Out[33]: {x: 1}
```

So the situation for `solve([Eq(x, 1), Eq(x, t)], [x])` is that there does exist a solution if `t=1` but no solution exists for *every other possible value* of `t`.

The question is sometimes asked: why can't `solve` figure out that `t=1` and so solve the equations returning `x=1`?

The problem is that `solve` is not free to choose a value for `t` because it is not one of the *unknowns*. Suppose hypothetically that `t` is a symbol representing some constant like the speed of light or something: its value cannot be freely chosen by `solve`! Alternatively `t` might mean time and `x` might be something that is supposed to be a function of time. It is not for solve to return a result that is only valid for one particular time `t=1`.

The expectation is that you might substitute a value for `t` later say like `t=3`. So `solve` should return something that would be valid for all possible values of `t` or at least most possible values or something like that. Here for *almost all* possible values of `t` the system `{x=1, x=t}` has no solutions.

If we want `solve` to figure out that `t=1` and then find the solution for `x` then we need to give it the freedom to do so by allowing `t` to be one of the unknowns listed in the second argument to `solve`:

```
In [34]: solve([Eq(x, 1), Eq(x, t)], [x, t])
Out[34]: {t: 1, x: 1}
```

Here since `t` is an unknown `solve` can establish that `t=1`. When `t` was not included in the unknowns it was treated as a symbolic parameter. For a symbolic parameter `solve` should try to return something that is correct for as many values of that parameter as possible which it does by returning a result that is valid for the *generic* case (in so far as that is possible). The result for the generic case means that we have to consider `t` as an arbitrary complex number and if for almost all complex values of `t` there are no solutions then *generically* the system has no solutions and so the empty list `[]` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your logic is reversed: a single variable cannot have multiple values but each value could be expressed in terms of the variable. For example `x == a == b/2` is only true if `a == b == 0`. Ask solve to solve for all except lambda and you will get your solution:

```py
>>> solve(equations, exclude=lambdas)
{α00: λ0, α01: 3*λ0, α10: 2*λ0, α11: 4*λ0}
>>> same = lambdas + [solve(Eq(k,v),lambdas[0])[0] for k,v in sol.items()]
>>> ' == '.join([str(i) for i in same])
λ0 == α00 == α01/3 == α10/2 == α11/4
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, I believe the issue is related to how you're defining the variables in your equations.

To solve this issue, I suggest the following changes to your code:

1 - Make sure you import the necessary functions and classes from SymPy:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
```

2 - Define the variables correctly using `symbols`:

```
λ0, α00, α01, α10, α11 = symbols('λ0 α00 α01 α10 α11')
```

3 - Create a list of equations with the defined variables:

```
equations = [Eq(λ0, α00), Eq(3*λ0, α01), Eq(2*λ0, α10), Eq(4*λ0, α11)]
```

4 - Solve the system of equations:

```
lambdas = [λ0]
solution = solve(equations, lambdas)
```

5 - print the solution:

```
print(solution)
```

The output should show the desired relationship between the variables:

```
{λ0: α00, α01: 3*α00, α10: 2*α00, α11: 4*α00}
```

Note that the solution is expressed in terms of α00, so you may still need to substitute the actual values for the other α parameters to obtain the numerical value for λ0.

Comment: i tried exactly what u suggested in the python idle it still gives me []

Comment: also in sympylive it gives []